# How do I export a PApplet to make it runnable in a browser?

Tags: java, eclipse, applet, processing

I have an Eclipse Java project, in which I have an src/demo package that contains a Processing demo, inside a single class that extends `PApplet`. The demo runs fine in Eclipse.

I wish to demo this package, preferably in a web browser. Being able to *demo* outside the Eclipse project would still be appreciated.

I've tried exporting the package to a JAR and embedding it in an HTML file. Firefox seems to be the only modern mainstream browser that supports NPAPI plugins like Java (Chrome 46 just shows a grey box, Safari 9 shows a blank page).
Firefox kept throwing "Class/Library not found" errors, until I manually copied all the libraries to the same directory as a JAR and including them in `archive` attribute of the `applet` element in the HTML.

Now Firefox shows a black outline but a blank app, which might because I haven't copied assets from the `data` folder in Eclipse. I have no idea how to include them with the JAR however.

I tried following [this guide](https://github.com/processing/processing/wiki/Export-Info-and-Tips) and simply adding a `main()` to the `PApplet` but that gave me a "Class not found error" when I exported it as a runnable JAR and tried running it.

System information: Mac OS X 10.11.0, Java 1.8.60

What is the systematic way to go about all this?

Comment: Have fun trying to run an applet in a browser in 2015...

Comment: For the record, Firefox is going to disable NPAPI soon as well, except for Flash.

Comment: @immibis, indeed...I'm open to converting it into an ordinary Java app, but I couldn't find any examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way to answer your question is to clear up some of the confusions you have about the issues you're experiencing.

First of all, applets are pretty much dead. They won't work at all in chrome, like you mentioned. Getting them to work in other browsers is a pain in the neck, for you **and** for your end users. You have to either pay for a certificate or get your users to change their Java security settings.

Furthermore, as of Processing 3, PApplet no longer extends Applet. So you can't simply extend PApplet and treat it as an applet anymore. (You forgot to tell us which version of Processing you're using.)

Honestly, the best approach is to forget about applets.

If you forget about applets, then you could deploy as a standard executable by  going to file -> export, or as a runnable jar using something like [JarMatey](http://staticvoidgames.com/JarMatey/) (full disclosure: I wrote JarMatey). It's important to note that it's **not** enough to simply add a `main()` function to your class.

But in my honest opinion, your best bet for deploying your Processing sketch is to use [Processing.js](http://processingjs.org/) to deploy as html5/JavaScript. This should be pretty easy, as long as you aren't using any Java libraries.

Comment: I am using Java libraries though, so Processing.js isn't an option unfortunately. However, I just realised that all I had to do to turn it into a Java application was to add a main method and call a helper to make it run as an application. Trying to figure out how to export this atm. I seem to keep getting "Could not find main method" errors when exporting to Runnable JAR even though it runs fine as an application in Eclipse.

Comment: Never mind, I deleted all my previous launch configs and exporting works like a charm now